# Hotfix - commit file including Version Number Change?

Tags: git-flow, gitkraken

I'm using Gitkraken's gitflow:

https://support.gitkraken.com/repositories/git-flow

My fix basically requires changing a single HTML file, a class on a single element. I also want to change the version number in my app (it's a Windows store app, changing the `package.appxmanifest` file from 4.1.2 to 4.1.3).

My intuition is to (a) start the Hotfix branch, (b) commit the HTML change, (c) another commit for the version change in the appxmanifest file, and then (d) finish the hotfix, merging it into Master and Develop. Is that correct? If not, what's the order of operations?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably You've found the answer during this time, but in case someone else finds this page then this answer might be helpful:

If this is an urgent fix for critical, out-of-cycle releases into production as Hotfix stands for, then yes, this is correct order.
In case it's a fix that can wait for future release then this should be handled as regular development and next order should be used: feature->develop->release->master

Comment: Just for clarity, in your last example, what happens in the 'release' branch? What sorts of commits go in there?